# jQuery UI - restore basic style and functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have an application with old code. This code somehow interfere with the functionality and style of jQuery UI elements.

Let's say that I want to have a tooltip on a span. After I initialize the tooltip, it appears somehow at the edge of the screen (`left: 0px;`).

I think this is caused by the intersection of the current application code (style or js) and the jQuery UI code.

I am not sure where the problem comes and I think it's nearly impossible to determine.

The question is, is there any way to "isolate" somehow my jQuery UI elements so that they will work and look properly?

Comment: try providing `!important` attribute to your `tooltip` styles..

Comment: Do you mean the jQuery UI tooltip styles? This can't be done.

Comment: It can be done!! You can change the `jQuery-ui.css` styles..

Answer (score 1):

The only way to "isolate" jQuery-ui from your custom CSS is to use CSS classes other than jQuery-ui. All jQuery classes starts with `.ui-*` so you will have to create as many classes as you want but they shouldn't be prefixed with `ui-`.

I advise you to not change jQuery styles so you can update the library without causing problems.

Another solution is to use a CSS Selector Scope. You can implement the solution in the [download builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/) which automates the process of applying scope to a theme. The theme scope field is where you'll enter a CSS selector representing a portion of your page (or your site) that your theme should apply.
([read more here](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using-multiple-jquery-ui-themes-on-a-single-page.html))

Hope this help you.